# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, foreign-keys, eloquent

I am recieving the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`messages`, CONSTRAINT `messages_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `messages` (`subject`, `message`, `draft`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, testgdsgds, 0, 2015-05-24 16:03:59, 2015-05-24 16:03:59))
```

So from this I can see that it relates to my sender_id field in the messages table. Here is the migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->mediumText('subject');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->boolean('draft');
            $table->integer('sender_id')->unsigned();;
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

And here is where I save the information:

**ApiController.php**

```
public function store()
    {
        $userId = Sentry::getUser()->id;

        $input = Input::all();

        //Create Message
        Message::create([
            'subject' => $input['subject'],
            'message' => $input['message'],
            'draft'   => 0,
            'sender_id' => $userId
        ]);    
    }
```

**EmailRepositoryEloquent.php**

```
public function create(array $data)
    {    
        $model = $this->model->fill($data);

        if ($model->save()) return $model;

        return false;
    }
```

I can confirm that the data is being passed correctly between all the methods, so I am currently user one and in the `$data` array that is being passed to the `create()` method the `sender_id` is 1. There is definitely a user for this ID as well as I am logged in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dondraper_ in the Larachat slack channel, i figured out that when I recently updated the column name from user_id to sender_id I forgot to change the $fillable value. Once $fillable was updated to 'sender_id' it all worked!

Answer (score 0):

"A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table."

And if value you are inserting is not present in parent table cause foreign key constraint fails.

for reference please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html.